# Is that valid XML and how to replicate with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I do have to replicate an XML file with SQL Server and I am now stumbling over the following structure inside the XML file and I don't know how to replicate that.

The structure looks like this at the moment for certain tags:

```
        <ART_TAG1>
            <UNMLIMITED/>
        </ART_TAG1>
        <ART_TAG2>
            <ART_TAG3>
                <Data_Entry/>
            </ART_TAG3>
        </ART_TAG2>
```

I am wondering if this is proper XML that the data inside (unlimited and Data_Entry) is enclosed with a closing XML tag. The XML validator https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp is telling me this is correct. But now I am struggling with replicating that with Transact-SQL.

If I try to replicate that I can only come up with the following TSQL script, which obviously does not fully look like the original.

```
  SELECT 'UNLIMITED' as 'ART_TAG1'
    , 'Data_Entry' as 'ART_TAG2/ART_TAG3'
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('root')

  <root>
  <ART_TAG1>UNLIMITED</ART_TAG1>
  <ART_TAG2>
  <ART_TAG3>Data_Entry</ART_TAG3>
  </ART_TAG2>
  </root>
```

Comment: You have three different questions here: 1. How to replicate data (there are many ways) 2. Is this valid XML (Yes) 3. How do I get my `FOR XML` to work. What problem are you actually having?

Comment: I basically am only interested in the third question, how is it possible to add data values inside tags. I am able to insert the data as, 'unlimited' or 'Data_Entry', but can't enclose them with <, />.

Comment: XML can be simply represented as a string. So you can always fall abck to string operations. But it seems now you have a _fourth_ question - you want to add data to existing XML. In XML, `<UNMLIMITED/>` is equivalent to `<UNMLIMITED></UNMLIMITED>`. Now do you want to add data like this: `<UNMLIMITED>MyData</UNMLIMITED>` or this `<UNMLIMITED data="MyData"></UNMLIMITED>`

Comment: Can you edit your question to be specific about what you want to do with examples. What data type is this stored in? `XML` or `VARCHAR`? Are you trying to add data to existing XML or are you trying to select it out and add it on the fly?

Comment: I am selecting data on the fly and add it to a XML datatype. This is all working pretty nicely. The issue I am having is with how to convert information from the database, like the string `Data_Entry´ and add it as <Data_Entry/> to the resulting XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this correctly, your question is:

> How can I put my query to create those `<SomeElement />` tags?

Look at this:

--This will create **filled** nodes

```
SELECT 'outer' AS [OuterNode/@attr]
      ,'inner' AS [OuterNode/InnerNode]
FOR XML PATH('row');
```

--The **empty string** is some kind of content

```
SELECT 'outer' AS [OuterNode/@attr]
      ,'' AS [OuterNode/InnerNode]
FOR XML PATH('row');
```

--the missing value (`NULL`) is omited by default

```
SELECT 'outer' AS [OuterNode/@attr]
      ,NULL AS [OuterNode/InnerNode]
FOR XML PATH('row');
```

--Now check what happens here:
--First XML has an empty element, while the second uses the self-closing element

```
DECLARE @xml1 XML=
N'<row>
  <OuterNode attr="outer">
    <InnerNode></InnerNode>
  </OuterNode>
</row>';

DECLARE @xml2 XML=
N'<row>
  <OuterNode attr="outer">
    <InnerNode/>
  </OuterNode>
</row>';

SELECT @xml1,@xml2;
```

The result is the same for both...

Some background: Semantically the empty element `<element></element>` is exactly the same as the self-closing element `<element />`. It should not make any difference, whether you use the one or the other. If your consumer cannot deal with this, it is a problem in the reading part.

Yes, you can force any content into XML on string level, but - as the example shows above - this is just a (dangerous) hack.

XML within T-SQL returns - by default - a missing node as `NULL` and an empty element as *empty* (depending on the datatype, and beware of the difference between an element and its `text()` node).

In short: This is nothing you should have to think about...

Comment: The weird thing in my example XML is that the name ´InnerNode` actually is a value from the database and carries information. So for example inside a tag <Duration> it currently includes <unlimited/> and a closing </Duration>. So that's what confuses me.

Comment: @hannes101 well, that's really dangerous and should be changed. Is this under your control?

Comment: I think this XML schema is based on that definition. And the issue can be found for example with element ART_LAUFZEIT. https://www.bundesbank.de/resource/blob/612644/fbf18c981deaa1f404b57ed64db565f9/mL/bbk-xml-spezielles-schema-xsd-data.raw

Comment: And if I need to create such an XML I need to write an empty tag with the information.

Comment: @hannes101 Use the empty string to create the *empty element*. Should be the same

Comment: The issue with that approach is that it's working if there's only one possible value for the name of the tag. But for certain tags, there are a whole bunch of possible entries and I can't figure out to dynamically name the  XML tag. Check for example the possible entries in the art_inhaber_offen tag of the schema linked above.